# While it is possible to have no cycles in an array input, how does applying cycle sort to such an input fare in terms of efficiency?

Tags: algorithm

Consider example input Array = [7,5,0,1] and sorted output array = [0,1,5,7].
As it can be seen in this example, there are no cycles. If I were to apply cycle sort to such an input, would there be any difference in the speed ? Cycle sort works on the principle of rotating the cycles to generate the sorted output. In an input where there are no cycles, what would be the benefit of using cycle sort ?

Comment: Would there be any difference in the speed **compared to what**? You have to look no further than time complexity to understand why every other API favours quick sort or merge sort above any O(n^2) complexity algorithm. It's apparently "theoretically optimal in terms of the total number of writes to the original array", which is perhaps the only reason one might consider using it in practice under certain (rare) circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand it is only optimal in terms of the writes to original array. But since it is built around the principle of rotating cycles in an array, I was wondering if the absence of those cycles has any effect on the performance at all. Trying to understand how important is the existence of cycles in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go for cycle sort as it takes worst case time complexity of O(n^2), instead you can think of making use of count sort if you know the value of maximum element of the array, count sort takes O(n) time or you can go with standard merge sort algorithm which takes in O(nlogn) time.